# Custom Radio Button with State List Drawable not Changing

Tags: android, xml

I have a set of `Radio Buttons` in a `RadioGroup`. I have created a `StateList Drawable` to indicate the state of each button. The buttons operate properly in that selecting any one will kick off the listeners, etc. However, the `StateList Drawable` isn't working. Here's the relevant stuff:

Layout XML with button:

```
            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/score4"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/score_button_selector" />
```

score_button_selector xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/score_bg_2c_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/score_bg_2c_off"/>

</selector>
```

`score_bg_2c_off` is a blue button:

[image]

and `score_bg_2c_on` is a green button:

[image]

The blue button appears properly, but when selected (pressed/clicked), the green one should appear instead. As I said, the operation of the button is fine, I get it's value properly, etc. - just not the drawable change. I tried `state_selected` instead of `state_checked` with no better results.

Any ideas why this isn't working as I'd like?

Thanks.

Here's some more data... I took out the `android:button=` and put the drawable on the `android:background=`.

```
            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/score4"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/score_button_selector" />
```

This way the default radio button shows up. This button shows when it is selected (blue inside the button), but the background never changes. I know it's seeing the `score_button_selector` drawable because it's showing the button with the blue background that is only defined in the drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing a good *project clean* can't fix! I think that perhaps a majority of the time doing a *clean* as a last resort b-4 posting a question is a good protocol. It cleared this problem up after chasing ghosts for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/score4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/score_button_selector" />
```

Comment: I assume you meant to have `android:button` in the last line and not `android:background`. In any case, ... nope.

Comment: I updated my code. Nope, last line will be background. You need to make button transparent.

Comment: Still no joy. The button is transparent, but the background never changes.

Comment: You mean it is Blue but it is not turning to green when you click on it?

Comment: Email me your code so I can take a look. My email is in my profile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45950/discussion-between-gokhan-arik-and-ddk)